# CSS (hover): How to change all elements (in one 'box') in some way but one element in another way?

Tags: css, xml

I'm working with XML and CSS. I need to add different shadowing for one of the parent's elements by mousing over this parent (box). But I can only use CSS. Is it possible to do that?

I was trying by adding hover selector for this specific element (as parent's (box's) child) but still shadowing only showed when I moused over this text.
I tried also some `:not(:hover)` things but this is also not the effect I want.

```xml
<registration>
    <worker ID_worker="115">
        <name>Name</name>
        <surname>Surname</surname>
        <date_of_birth>14-05-1980</date_of_birth>
    </worker>
    <activity_type type="4">
        <activity>Some activity</activity>
        <details>Some details</details>
    </activity_type>
    <date>05-29-2019</date>
    <duration>8:12:18</duration>
</registration>
```

```css
registration:hover {
    background-color: RGB(13, 21, 25);
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

This code provides changing background, border and adding shadow for whole text in XML's 'registration' when I mouse over registration box. But now I need text in 'activity_type' to have different color of shadow. Again - I can only use CSS.
Would be grateful if someone just tell me is it reachable in CSS?

Comment: `registration:hover activity_type { /* stuff here */ }` …?

Comment: 04FS: Oh dear, it's working! How I didn't come up with this... Thank you :)